# Does Google Chrome Cast iOS SDK supports Fairplay and AES encryption

Tags: ios, google-cast, http-live-streaming, fairplay

My app plays HLS streams and supports both Fairplay DRM and basic AES 128 encrypted HLS streams.

My player implements `AVAssetResourceLoaderDelegate` to decode both encryption methods.

Now i'm looking for Chrome Cast support, but while reading the documentation, I have the feeling I cannot have access to `AVAssetResourceLoaderDelegate` when streaming to Chrome Cast.

According to [the doc](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/ios_sender_integrate), developer should create a `GCKMediaInformation` with the media URL, give it to Chrome Cast SDK, it does its secret sauce.

Is there a way to hook the HLS manifest reading and give CCast the keys to decrypt the streams?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I finaly found an answer in the doc.

> These are available through use of the Media Player Library, or you
> may use your own player library.
>
> ```
> MPEG-DASH
>     PlayReady (Security Level 2000)
>     Widevine (Level 1)
>
> SmoothStreaming
>     PlayReady (Security Level 2000)
>
> HTTP Live Streaming (HLS)
>     AES-128 encryption
>     Raw MP3 segments can be part of an HLS media playlist
>
> Progressive download without adaptive switching (using the HTML media element only)
> ```
>
> With adaptive bitrate streaming protocols, you must implement CORS. To
> implement an encrypted protocol, including DRM, you should develop a
> Custom Receiver. See DRM support for more information.

For AES encrypted streams, it would be ok, <s>but for FairPlay stream, I need to develop a ["custom receiver" app](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/receiver_apps)</s>

Comment: You won't be able to develop a custom receiver app with FairPlay support. The DRM support can't be done in JavaScript, so you have to use what's available - in this case Widevine or PlayReady if you need "real" DRM or AES (or no) encryption.